# Disconnect points to plot overlay in Vega-lite / Vega

Tags: plot, data-science, vega, anomaly-detection, vega-lite

An example in vega-editor [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-Vj8cTyfFaYz8VTEGpAcgyCU1U0ouofPGkAAHvLbUm9aYkdD+orhQBHVjGozRIxUf2Hpmnxjn5Xu6O35UHyfZgokYN9VzAVMGiAA)

I don’t want dateTime 5 & dateTime 7 to be connected since they are not consecutive. Idea is to plot on overlay based on some condition and connect only when the count is >=5.

Has anyone tried this already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace your filter statement:

```
{"filter": "datum.count >= 5"}
```

With a calculate statement that sets filtered values to null:

```
{"as": "count", "calculate": "if(datum.count >= 5, datum.count, null)"}
```

The result is [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-Q7KkpXWIAJT65qrNbwZ2ugrKy5qyC25XsW3ICSqhrWsC0nKSssyuWxBWC4XwRi6eA2HPVDVaqA6vUGvBGk3m3SWnAclN5U2MMQdLvrP0BinBsPZhGQtNiF1u4XZ-p50wF2BF0XissV+KliDU5OQZBKaqaUXUPnjSAAD3lk6LetMSOh-UVwoAI6sMaRjREYVBJi+TIfowX72hSOYAcqwGgcwUSMJBF5gKWDRAA)

[image]