# vega-lite line plot - color not getting applied in transform filter

Tags: vega, vega-lite

Vega Editor link [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

I've an overlay color change based on filter condition in a multi line chart. Got it working with single line [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53840675/649451) but 'red' overlay line(along with red dot) doesn't come up with this above multi-line example. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: your chart is working, except the filtered values are not colored red.

The core issue is that encodings always supersede mark properties, as you can see in this simpler example: [editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckAIJgE6Asl2Ex3PJcTcA7oyXUwL3bGSE3WzB0JU0wVEYxHTBCINoxByVYOjUNSE1rTBxgSFZdMWwtTNJ4dF95RRUAX3UISAxdAGtCnLwAT1jCyACPPDUoeG4HXS7dZE1IGrTkJUHND2oWjTqADxbIADNGZDEJ0wAJbl9-QJHVKHbO0wBHVhCjPGtGKknaiCg29a2dvagAWUiOgA+rFdECAOLoBLKfqQS7ILq3e7MJ4vKbvAZDI5fba7LoAeX0TBU5zhHQRpiU3AiSihr2WUFgiHQVzAOW+eNMhMYxNh8K6VJpdKqGhFIqAA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "description": "A scatterplot showing horsepower and miles per gallons.",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": {"type": "point", "color": "red"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "Origin", "type": "nominal"},
    "shape": {"field": "Origin", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Notice that although we specify that the mark should have color red, this is overridden by the color encoding. This is by design within Vega-Lite, because encodings are more specific than properties.

Back to your chart: because you specify the color encoding in the parent chart, each individual layer inherits that color encoding, and those colors override the `"color": "red"` that you specify in the individual layers.

To make it do what you want, you can move the color encoding into the individual layers (and use a `detail` encoding to ensure the data are still grouped by that field). For example ([editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "data": {...},
  "width": 1000,
  "height": 200,
  "autosize": {"type": "pad", "resize": true},
  "transform": [
    {
      "window": [{"op": "rank", "as": "rank"}],
      "sort": [{"field": "dateTime", "order": "descending"}]
    },
    {"filter": "datum.rank <= 100"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line"},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "name",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {"title": "Type"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "red"},
      "transform": [
        {
          "as": "count",
          "calculate": "if(datum.anomaly == true, datum.count, null)"
        },
        {"calculate": "true", "as": "baseline"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "color": "red"},
      "transform": [
        {"filter": "datum.anomaly == true"},
        {"calculate": "true", "as": "baseline"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "dateTime",
      "type": "temporal",
      "timeUnit": "hoursminutesseconds",
      "sort": {"field": "dateTime", "op": "count", "order": "descending"},
      "axis": {"title": "Time", "grid": false}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "count",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "axis": {"title": "Count", "grid": false}
    },
    "detail": {"field": "name", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm just wondering why a `red` value `condition` within the `color` channel could not be used instead of filtering and then coloring. ... edit: after reading the spec by the OP, I have noticed that it appears to be about the `line`, which changes of course the behavior of `color`. Still, for the `circle` mark, I think the question holds, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you could probably also do this with a conditional color layer (red vs transparent) instead of a filter layer. The difference is the filter avoids the display of transparent points.

Comment: @jakevdp Thanks a lot for this detailed answer :)